Can water magic be effective?
Can a spell that creates a 1m by 1m rectangle of water up to 20 m long be effective in combat, assuming this is your only spell and the rectangle extends at a rate of 5m/sec? Essentially, can it do enough damage to enemy soldiers to be more effective than a spear or other normal weapon? Tech level is around the pike and shot era. The spell converts air into an equivalent volume of water but does not convert non-air matter in the way. The water does not hold its rectangular shape, and the rectangle originates from the mage's hand. A caster carries enough mana to cast about 50 spells before needing to get more mana from a carrier squad, and mages are common enough that every tercio formation(it's the best for combat in this era and is used by all nations) has around 1 mage for every 50 regular soldiers.

I don't know about fighting, but being able to cross (or retreat safely into) areas which don't have potable water would be a huge advantage for an army.  Sieges would be different.  And there would be clever indirect things (like setting a counterweight to a catapult?) which could be exploited by the clever...

Yes, infinite energy is a useful thing to have, in combat or in any other situation. VTC as hopelessly underspecified. (My pet peeve is with the "rectangle". After 200 milliseconds the mage has converted 1 cubic meter of air into 1 tonne of water; fine, great magicking. But the water is, you know, a fluid, and it won't stay in the shape of a cube: it will flow down and form a large sloshing puddle.)

Having the highground and a couple mages each producing 5 tons of water per second seems like an easy way to undermine your enemy's position

How far away from the mage can the water materialize? For instance, does that 1m by 1m rectangle start by extending from their hand? Or could they start materializing it 100m above them in the air?

The rectangle starts from their hand. I suppose I should have been more clear about that.

Since you already have well-intentioned answers which didn't get your unclear intent, I think you should self-close and make a new question with more information:

Such as... the rectangle starts from the mage's hand. The water is created stationary, not moving at 5m/s. (relative to what? the mage? the ground? both i.e. the mage must be stationary?) Is the air in lungs, porous substances, etc, excluded, as if these things slipped into a pool of water, or is it instantly magically replaced? Is the water constrained to remain in the prism? If so, is it constrained as if by gravity, or as if by a fixed-shape container? I.e. if I run into it, do I go sploosh, or crunch? ...

Does the water, or its prism shape constraint, go away after some time, or is one or both permanent? If the water goes away, when? And is it gently replaced by air, like it gently replaced the air in the first place? Does the prism have to be horizontal?

You don't need to specify all of those if you want answers to play with them, but do nail down the ones you care about.

In addition, you can make this question fit Worldbuilding better by specifying what you want your world to look like (you have this already - militaries which find it useful to fight in pike and shot formations, but which also have 1/50 men as described) and the problem you are having in getting it there (tuning my mages' abilities and constraints within certain boundaries so that they make sense in this world), to make it a well-defined worldbuilding problem, as opposed to an off topic character problem or ability brainstorming.

VTC:Too Story-Based. You're asking us how to use your spell. That's writing your story for you (see [help/on-topic]). Any solution can be made to work if you write you story to accomodate it, which means all answers have equal value, which is prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. This was a great question for the Story Tellers Corner.

I asked the specific question "Can it do enough damage to be more effective than a spear or other normal weapon"? I'm fully aware of the implications of this spell in support roles and I want to ask how useful it would be in DIRECT combat.

It’s magic. Magic with rules vague enough for any answer you want to be valid. Do you want it to be more effective than a spear then in your world it will be. We’re not here to reassure you about your worldbuilding choices. Build the world you want and tell compelling stories in it.

Why? I have laid out the rules of my magic. They are not vague at all. The water prism holds firm in all cases. No more, no less. Given such specific rules I would expect that it would be possible to determine whether it would be an objectively good weapon compared to other weapons of the time.

I can't simply say "this is more effective than a spear." If I replaced the spell in the question with a spell of singular rabbit summoning that makes a single normal rabbit appear, i can't say it's more effective than a cannon. It won't make any sense. Similar to this, I can't simply say this water spell is better than a spear. I need an answer that shows how it will cause damage to enemies better than a spear. If I replaced the spell with a gun that replaces the air with water, would I be able to arbitrarily say it is superior to a normal gun because it is "magic"? No, I would not.

In the bedroom, it definitely can.

@IMP9024 with what you've specified in your comments, this question becomes a bit silly doesn't it? You're asking us whether a spell that deals no damage would deal more damage than a spear, in which case the answer is clearly no, because you've described a spell that does not deal damage.

@M S it might. For example, you can drop the water on top of them. I'm unsure what kind of physical damage this would cause to humans though.

The Drowning Squad
As your magic converts air into water, any enemy in range could be drowned. Mages would convert the air in their lungs to water and immediately stop them in their tracks.
Support Squad
While that is a large volume of water, it is not moving that fast. The average wind wave in the ocean is about 5m/s as well. Just as you are pushed back and swept of your feet as you are wading into the ocean, so too would the enemy troops. It would be an effective method of holding a large number of foot soldiers back while a mounted regiment encircles.
Fighting in the Mud
In most warfare, picking the battle field is a strategy choice. There are countless examples of battle hills and defendable positions turning the tide of a battle. If your mages could change the landscape by saturating the ground with water and turning the enemy's advance into a slog, they would become vulnerable to archers and other tactics.
Artillery and Arrow Defense
Most projectiles of that time would have enough energy to pass through a meter of water (in the scenario when your mage extends a barrier long ways). However, any angled barrie would deflect arrows and cannon balls away from your troops.

"It is not moving that fast": The way I read the question, the water is not moving at all. Air is converted to water in place, no movement.

The wall of water would fall immediately, so you’d have to time it perfectly to deflect a projectile as fast as a bullet or cannonball. Far too unreliable to be useful for that purpose.

Yes, the water doesn't move, rather the area of air that becomes water moves

"effective in combat"
Short answer: A mess.
I think the issue is that, if I understand correctly, you are limiting it to combat.
All in all I think it would create some interesting scenarios, but it's not OP enough to simply dominate the battlefield.
Direct usage: Chaos and confusion
Can be used in your favor, or against you. The enemy soldiers might feel refreshed by your water and keep fighting, they might run. Your own soldiers might misunderstand. They might go into random directions or advance while they should not. Not only are you in a melee but there is a lot of water. You probably can't see or hear your commander. And everyone panicking as they trying to figure out what is going on. I imagine perhaps some nations might develop a sort of super tall flags on most soldiers or commanders to assist soldiers. Many battles were lost simply because confusion.
Lets look at clever ways how I think a commander would use this magic.
Ground manipulation.
This could be a very useful tool in some places. You create a mixed unit. Sappers and mages, and you arm them with mounts and some ground breaking tools. Then you deploy the unit to some parts you want to break up. They flood the place with water and use the tools they have to mess up the ground further. Obviously this depends on the type of land and it's not like solider can never march through mud.
But if you do it right, you can slow down the enemy. Because large parts of the land is mini marches. They carts would get stuck, their soldiers won't appreciate knee high mud...etc...etc. This can also be combined with other tactics. Create such an artificial marsh on one side then take the higher ground. Now you can afford to direct more forces to other parts of the battlefield. And for defense you can maneuver smaller forces to hold the high ground since you know the enemy is slow in marching there.
MOATS
This is a more context based tactic. But if you have enough time. Have your soldiers dig as big a ditch as they can. Then...we flood it. Bang. You have a moat. Simple ditches existed. But in your world you can make it insanely effective.
Soldiers are no strangers to digging, and you literally make water out of thin air.
This creates a very strong defensive line that the enemy would have to navigate. Yes. The enemy can fill it. But that takes time, and all the while you are doing something, missiles or whatever.
Retreats.
They just became a lot easier. Your mages just flood the place with water while your soldiers simply run away. But wait. What if you train your soldiers to fake a retreat? Force the enemy to think you are running then have them walk into a trap.
Fates of nations were decided by one weak section on a front.
Logistics
Supplying the army&animals with water is always a major issue. Battles are fought over water, denying the enemy water is as old as time. All those things kinda become trivial as your mage can simply conjure up water. Even if it's not super clean, you can still boil it. This makes marching into deserts a very different thing.
Any nation that has a gigantic super hot water scarce desert that they relied on for protection. they become instantly a valid target. Sieges change.
Marching changes, baggage train change...etc.
Because food you easily store and preserve for longer periods, but not water. And water is heavy.
Cloaking.
This is rather a very good point. If you can get together enough mages, on say horses for easier maneuvering, to create a solid wall of water in front of your formation then the enemy sure as heck won't know where you are hiding that cavalry unit or keeping the elites.
This is a very powerful tool. As it always you to hide parts of your army. Maybe you are putting a phalanx type unit in the center, maybe that large wall of water to the side is nothing but a decoy, maybe it's meant to look like a decoy and your cavalry are there...etc.
Any commander would love the idea of being able to hide parts of his army or trick the enemy into thinking so.
Yes. The size is not gigantic but you can manipulate this well enough to at least fool people from afar, or get your mages to "stack" their spell to create larger walls.
Anti cavalry
I have no idea how cavalry reacts to this. Humans can be trained to understand that the wall of water is just water and they simply move through it.
Cold
I'd not want to be a soldier in cold environments having to fight people who can turn air into water. Yes. Historically speaking Winter, say in Europe, was not a campaigning season. But some winter combat happened. The worst scenario is when it's not cold enough to turn the water into snow but but cold enough to get you sick if you get wet and not dry off.
Ice
This is obviously limited to location and season. But I imagine that it becomes a nightmare trying to invade any nation with those mages and a cold lands.
Like all you have to do to stop any number of invaders is deploy your mages and have them conjure up water all over the place, water turns to ice. Yes, ice is not indestructible. But no invading army wants to have to clear thousands of kilometers of ice all the while the defending nation is preparing for the invasion.
And in actual combat, your mages has the ability to create walls of ice that the enemy has to destroy. Retreating became a lot easier.
Please notice I understand that the enemy army has weapons. But fun fact, most weapons are not designed to destroy ice. Even axe. Actual battle axes tended to be a lot thinner, spears are just a long piece of wood with a metal head, swords are thin...etc. Halberds are a lot better though. But in any case you force the enemy to either create small points in your 30 km wide wall which is just creating natural choke points. Or they stand there trying to take down the whole thing.
